# How to load array data in string format in snowflake string based column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have spark dataframe with string type column like ['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}].
When I tried to insert using the above data surrounding double quotes getting error.

The query I used was:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_nm VALUES ('test_case01','Pass',"['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}]",'2023-01-02') ;
```

Error:
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 92 invalid identifier '"['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}]"'

It is working when I surround the string with single quote(') and replace inside ' with " like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_nm VALUES ('test_case01','Pass','["Match", {"src_cnt": "541", "tgt_cnt": "541"}]','2023-01-02') ;
```

But My data coming with ' inside square bracket['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}]

Could any one guide me how can I insert the data with ' inside square brackets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be I was not explained it clearly. After putting single quotes means, Usually we insert string data by enclosed with single quotes or double quotes. If I surrounded the data with double quotes it looks like "['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}]", which is giving me an error. If i enclosed the data with single quote and replace inner single quotes with double quotes like '["Match", {"src_cnt": "541", "tgt_cnt": "541"}]'.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your array in double dollar that will escape single and double quotes. Like this..

```
$$['Match', {'src_cnt': '541', 'tgt_cnt': '541'}]$$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rajat, It's working in snowflake web UI. 
But I have a common python method which inserts the data either snowflake or sqlite3 based on the option. It's working for snowflake. I am looking for common insert statement which I can use for both sqlite as well snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape single quotes by putting 2 single quotes. It should work on both Snowflake and Sqlite3:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_nm VALUES ('test_case01','Pass','[''Match", {''src_cnt'': ''541'', ''tgt_cnt'': ''541''}]','2023-01-02') ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gokhan Atil.
Unfortunately data was fixed inside square brackets. Coming from other sources, Means we can't edit it